# Firebase hosting static website not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host a static website on firebase. ( using macOS Catalina )
I installed firebase CLI with npm.
The directory of my website is called Knight
After logging in, I run this command:

```
firebase init
```

Then I chose the following:
***Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this folder?***

```
hosting
```

***What do you want to use as your public directory?***

```
public (I also tried dist and knight and Knight and KNIGHT)
```

***Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?***

```
Y ( I also tried No )
```

***File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite?***

```
N
```

Then the init process is done.
When I try `firebase serve` and I got to http://localhost:5000 I get the firebase welcome page.
[image]

How can I see my website? Did I do something wrong?

I can notice that firebase is not writing any files in my directory after I call firebase init.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. After searching for `firebase.json` on my machine I realized that firebase was writing the files in my user directory, instead of writing them where I called firebase init. So my path to `index.html` would look like:

```
/Users/DCI/Documents/Knight/index.html
```

But firebase is writing the files in:

```
/Users/DCI
```

So what I had to do is give `Documents/Knight` as a public directory for firebase init. After I did this I called firebase serve and firebase deploy and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The process that the Firebase CLI uses is pretty straightforward:

1. You run `firebase init` in a specific directory
2. Answer the "What do you want to use as your public directory?" question with the path to your `index.html` and other web files **relative to the directory where you run `firebase.init`**

Since you say that you have you web site in `Knight`, you should answer "What do you want to use as your public directory?" with `Knight`.

---

**Update**: It seems that you are running the `firebase init` command in the same directory where your `index.html` file is. In that case your "public direction" is `.`, since it's the same directory that the project is in.

Comment: I tried that, and that's what makes me so confused. It's still giving the same "welcome page". I am sure that I chose the right directory because when I choose the directory during the firebase init process I can see a .log file being created in my directory in which I have the index.html file.

Comment: It looks like the `index.html` is in the directory where you run `firebase init`. I added an update for that to my answer.